# How to insert a picture in my git page?

Tags: github, markdown

I have just built a git user page and I want to add a picture in my article. Then I use

```
![repo name](https://github.com/zhangyangyu/zhangyangyu.github.io/raw/master/images/how-to-build-a-user-page-on-github/p1.png)
```

I find this on the Web and if I put the path in browser I can see my picture. But in my article, it just appear as the text. Why? If it helps the content of my config file is:

```
markdown: rdiscount
pygments: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [are using](http://github.com/zhangyangyu/zhangyangyu.github.io/tree/master/_posts) Textile for your files, but Markdown syntax for the images.

To fix, use Markdown files, for example

```
2013-04-12-how-to-build-a-user-page-on-github.md
```

[`ref`](http://github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/tree/source/_posts)